# mexFunction referencing external header file

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I am trying to compile a C file using mex (MATLAB 2012b on MacOSX Lion). My project consists of three files:

1. The Header File where the main functionality is defined, [smdvquad.h](http://pastebin.com/iPpEXD5a)
2. The C implementation of smdvquad.h, namely [smdvquad.c](http://pastebin.com/TAA6L3TZ) which #includes smdvquad.h and
3. A C file containing the "mexFunction", namely [mxsmdvquad.c](http://pastebin.com/Tskz1fh4) which #includes smdvquad.h

The whole project compiles absolutely fine on Netbeans, but when I try to compile it using mex on MATLAB, i.e. using the command:

```
mex -largeArrayDims mxsmdvquad.c
```

the following error is thrown:

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims mxsmdvquad.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_smdv_quad", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mxsmdvquad.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "mxsmdvquad.mexmaci64"' failed.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

I have also tried specifying the working directory using the -I mex-argument, i.e.

```
mex -largeArrayDims -I/path/to/my/project/ mxsmdvquad.c
```

but in vain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that one of the following would work:

Maybe you also need to compile `smdvquad.c`?

```
mex -largeArrayDims mxsmdvquad.c smdvquad.c
```

or if you already compiled smdvquad, you maybe need to link it:

```
mex -largeArrayDims mxsmdvquad.c smdvquad.o
```

or if it's in a different directory, you need to add the directory to the linker with `-L`:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -L/path/to/project mxsmdvquad.c smdvquad.o
```